# Bootstrap-table: popover & thumbnail:hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I make a bootstrap-table with images, and my idea is: when the user passes the mouse over the image, it enlarges. I tried to use popover but the only it's working with button I do not know to use popover with `<img>` tag.

A part from this I have tried to use css style .thumbnail:hover how this:

```
/* IMG HOVER */

.thumbnail:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
    left:-35px;
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 1px white solid;
    z-index:999;
}
```

This has a big problem when it enlarges the image, the row of the table grows too :( and it's deformed!

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DEMO ATTACHED

```css
.thumbnail:hover {
 

    transform: scale(10);

   
    
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" class="thumbnail" style="height:50px;width:50px"/></td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" class="thumbnail" style="height:50px;width:50px"/></td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" class="thumbnail" style="height:50px;width:50px"/></td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's easy! It's working fine! Thanks @Anil Panwar. Only a thing, Is it possilbe that not cut a part of image, ex: over of end of the table? I want to say this escale is not on top of everthing.

Comment: Please explain i don't get you.

Comment: I'm sorry! Yes! The images that are enlarge in the center of table has not problem but the images on top or bottom when it's enlarge are cutting part of this. The entire image is not see completely

Comment: If you see the demo the table has border and the image on top and bottom is not cutting on hover. Please have a look. Is this not what you desired as in DEMO?

Comment: You are right but in my code image is cut. It may be by the container or other reason ...

Answer (score 1):

I tried improving on the answer provided by @Anil Panwar, And based on your feedback, I guess you are looking for something like below.

```
/* CSS */
.thumbnail:hover {
    transform: scale(3);
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -o-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    transition:0.25s;
}
tr:last-of-type .thumbnail:hover {
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/ORQxkA)**